# Kendo Grid does not aggregate

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo UI Complete v2013.2.918, trying to show a grid with aggregates by many columns related to one group column, the aggregates is only summing the latest row, I follow the examples on the kendo page and it looks the same but is not doing the sum. Any idea what is the issue?

this is my code:

```
detailGrid = $("#details_paginated_grid_table").kendoGrid({

columns: [
    { field: "CallDate", title: translate('DATE') },
    { field: "CallTime", title: translate('TIME') },
    { field: "From", title: translate('FROM') },
    { field: "Destination", title: translate('DESTINATION') },
    { field: "MaskedCalledNumber", title: translate('DIALNUMBER') },
    { field: "CallType", title: translate('CALLTYPE'), groupHeaderTemplate: "Name: #= value # total Call Type: #=count#" },
    { field: "CallDurationDisplay", title: translate('MINUTES'), footerTemplate: "Total: #=sum#", groupFooterTemplate: "Minutes: #=sum#", aggregates: ["sum"] },
    { field: "CallRateDisplay", title: translate('RATE'), footerTemplate: "Total: #=sum#", groupFooterTemplate: "Rate: #=sum#", aggregates: ["sum"] },
    { field: "LongDistanceChargeDisplay", title: translate('LD'), footerTemplate: "Total: #=sum#", groupFooterTemplate: "LD: #=sum#", aggregates: ["sum"] },
    { field: "PktDtVolDisplay", title: translate('DATA'), footerTemplate: "Total: #=sum#", groupFooterTemplate: "Data: #=sum#", aggregates: ["sum"] },
    { field: "TotalChargesDisplay", title: translate('TOTAL'), footerTemplate: "Total: #=sum#", groupFooterTemplate: "Charges: #=sum#", aggregates: ["sum"] }                                                
],

dataSource: {
    data: [],

    group: {
        field: "CallType",
        aggregates: [
            { field: "CallDurationDisplay", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "CallRateDisplay", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "LongDistanceChargeDisplay", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "PktDtVolDisplay", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "TotalChargesDisplay", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "CallType", aggregate: "count" }
        ]
    },

    aggregate: [
        { field: "CallDurationDisplay", aggregate: "sum" },
        { field: "CallRateDisplay", aggregate: "sum" },
        { field: "LongDistanceChargeDisplay", aggregate: "sum" },
        { field: "PktDtVolDisplay", aggregate: "sum" },
        { field: "TotalChargesDisplay", aggregate: "sum" }
    ]
},
//sortable: false,
scrollable: false,
//pageable: false,
groupable: true,
height: 300,
```

});

Here an screenshot about the aggregates:

[image]

Comment: I change the kendo version to 2014.3.1411 and I have the same effect

Comment: Finally I found the issue, the columns were formatted to string in the view model :(, I change the data type and it works now